# Upgrading to Firefox 3.6 in ubuntu 9.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-9.04, firefox

I've downloaded Firefox 3.6 from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/upgrade.html unfortunately I don't find how to install it.

I've found a few articles on how to install alpha versions, but not this official release.

It should be very easy right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've finally found it.

In the update page: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/update/

Takes you to the step by step guide: https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Installing+Firefox+on+Linux

Firefox updates itself, we can check manually if there are updates: https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Updating+Firefox#Manually_check_for_updates

But in Ubuntu Firefox is automatically updated by the package manager, so the manual update will be disabled: https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Check+for+Updates+is+disabled

If that happen you will be lead to directions on how to install firefox on linux: https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Installing+Firefox+on+Linux

In this case we want up update from outside the package management: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion

That at the end tell us how up upgrade with  the official instructions: https://edge.launchpad.net/+help/soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html

At this point I quit. I'm using Ubuntu because I don't want to deal with all this problematic steps of going from one page to another and add strange directions to simply install a product.

I guess I'll have to wait for the package manager to have the upgrade ( although If I understand well that will never happen, for I will only get upgrades in the 3.0 line )

Anyway, if anyone knows how to do something as simple as a double click on installer ( or much better, drag and drop on Applications as in OSX ) let me know, would you?

Answer (score 0):

The last link in your answer has instructions for adding a third party package archive (PPA). And the second to last link has the location for the Firefox latest stable PPA. Combine those two pieces and you can add a PPA with the latest Firefox stable release.

---

**Edited for clarification:** the FirefoxNewVersion page links to the [PPA description](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-stable?field.series_filter=jaunty) where you can find the `deb` lines under "Technical details about this PPA".

Comment: I didn't found that page :-/ I followed the "Official instructions"  but got stuck on **Step 6:** *Now copy the second line from the apt sources.list entries section of the PPA overview page and paste it in just as you did in steps 4 and 5.*   WHAT sources.list entries?

Comment: The sources.list entries are the lines that start with 'deb' or 'deb-src'. There are two lines (one 'deb' and one 'deb-src') to add to the Third Party Software list on the PPA overview page.